# How to test a FIDO U2F USB token on the command line?

Tags: command-line, u2f

How can I speak the UAF (Universal Authentication Framework) and/or U2F (Universal Second Factor) = CTAPI protocols on the Linux cmdline ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *libfido2* library comes with tools which support both U2F and FIDO2 protocols:

- `fido2-token`
- `fido2-cred`
- `fido2-assert`

Older systems might instead have *libu2f-host*, which only supports U2F (CTAPv1):

- `u2f-host -a register`
- `u2f-host -a authenticate`

For example:

```
$ echo '{"version":"U2F_V2","appId":"https://example.com","challenge":"asdfghj"}' > reg.json
$ u2f-host -a register -o https://example.com < reg.json > reg_reply.json
[touch token]
```